# What does the word "framed" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, british-english, literature

> For a split second, Uncle Vernon stood framed in the doorway; then he
> let out a bellow like an angry bull and dived at Harry, grabbing him
> by the ankle.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

What does the word "framed" mean in this context?

In Cambridge Dictionary, the meaning is "to be between a border", but it doesn't make sense here sense it's a Person.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary definition is correct here, but it may make more sense to you if you understand that "framed" is expressly a reference to a *picture frame* or the *frame of a painting*.  When looking at a fancy painting, you can see an elaborate border around it, which is the frame.  When looking at Uncle Vernon, you can see a border around him-- namely, the doorway.

For an example, [this picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Indian_man_standing_in_doorway_%28Unsplash%29.jpg) depicts a man framed by a doorway.  See how the doorway can be seen surrounding the man.  He is "between the border" as the definition says.